# A way to use C#/Razor foreach loop get first 3 items, then wrap them in an element

Tags: c#, razor

I have a C#/Razor `foreach` loop with more than 3 items.

```
@foreach(var item in itemList){
    <div class="thing">@item.Name</dov?
}
```

So I can get the first three and wrap them using jQuery, JavaScript, etc. easily enough:

```
$('.thing').slice( 0, 3).wrapAll('<div class="firstThreeThings" style="border:1px solid blue"></div>');
```

But I would like to use C#/Razor to get the first three items in a list and wrap those three items in an element (`div`) and have the rest of the list wrapped in another element (`div`). Something equivalent to the jQuery above, just using Razor to do the wrap of the first three elements.

I have seen examples of getting the first three using `.Take(3)`. Which only gets the first three elements but how would I use this or another way to wrap the first three in an element (`div`) and the rest of the list (if larger than three elements) wrapped in another element (`div`)?

The desired effect would be something like:

```
<div class="firstThreeThings">
   <div class="thing">This is a thing</div>
   <div class="thing">This is a thing</div>
   <div class="thing">This is a thing</div>
</div>
<div class="otherThings">
   <div class="thing">This is a thing</div>
   <div class="thing">This is a thing</div>
   <div class="thing">This is a thing</div>
   <div class="thing">This is a thing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If separating the first 3 items is a business decision, meaning it is important to keep them separated, then it's better to create another list in the model, call it ImportantList and put only the first x elements.

Answer (score 2):

Just a blind idea

```
<div class="firstThreeThings">
    @foreach(var item in itemList.Take(3)){
       <div class="thing">@item.Name</div>
    }
</div>

<div class="otherThings">
    @foreach(var item in itemList.Skip(3)){
        <div class="thing">@item.Name</dov?
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Yeh, that will wrap the first 3 elements in their own divs.  I thought of that.  I will update my question to my desired effect.

Comment: Yeh, that makes sense. I will wrap those in something if the list contains more than 3 elements show the other list, if not, don't show it.  I did not know about the Skip, though I probably ran across it at some point.  Totally makes sense. I will give it a try and mark the solution as needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing this way in one of my projects, hope this helps:

```
@{
    var skip = 0;
    while (skip < Model.list.Count())
    {
    <tr>
        foreach (var parc in Model.list.Skip(skip).Take(3))
        {
            <td class="alinharCentroHorizontal">@parc.Seq</td>
            <td class="alinharCentroHorizontal">@parc.Date</td>
            <td class="alinharCentroHorizontal">@parc.Description</td>
            <td class="alinharCentroHorizontal">@parc.Value</td>
            skip++;
        }
    </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**